# C++ dll not returning to c#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke

I am working on a project that puts C# interacting with a previously created DLL in C++.
The code below shows how am I exporting the function I need:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int iterateAndTest(int testSize, char* testHash){

CUDADLL dll;
int ret = dll.iterateAndTest(testSize, testHash);
return ret;
}
```

The code below shows how I declare the function in C#:

```
[DllImport("C:\\Users\\BrunoBraga\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\CUDADLL\\Debug\\CUDADLL.dll")]
public static extern int iterateAndTest(int testSize, string testHash);
```

The problem is: the dll function is not returning anything. In fact, the dll once called, never returns to C# and the program simply ends.

I am not sure if I am giving the right code, but i suppose there is something about the dlls I am missing.

Sorry for the delay on response. THere were two problems:
1-When i created the object, i should have used new insted of just CUDADLL dll. I thought i could do this since without the new i was still able to access the inner fields.;

2-The program should run in admin, otherwise, some crashes would ocur;

Thanks again guys.

Comment: Have you tested that a) you are actually getting into the C++ method and the correct values are passed in and b) that it returns a value when called from other C++ code?

Comment: if it never return it might that it dies in the transison between managed/unmanaged code... which can have several reasons like a problem with the stack or some weirdness with memory handling etc.

Comment: yes. the arguments are being well passed. i printed them the calculations are beeing well done i checked but the function does not return :(

Comment: Sounds like an access violation or C++ exception was triggered.

Comment: the c++ ends the function and i checked it returns from the working function to the exporter header and then the program exits.

Comment: I'd pay attention to calling conventions: the default on C++ is `__cdecl`, instead I think the default for P/Invoke is `__stdcall`, so either make your function `__stdcall`, or try `CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl` with P/Invoke. Moreover, what is the encoding of your native string? Is the `char*` storing an ANSI string? If so, try adding `CharSet=CharSet.Ansi` to P/Invoke.

Comment: This normally happens when something goes wrong inside the unmanaged DLL. Let the application crash and try to debug it with JIT.

Comment: extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int iterateAndTest(int testSize, char* testHash){

 CUDADLL* dll = new CUDADLL();
 int ret = dll->iterateAndTest(testSize, testHash);
 return ret;
}

Comment: Debug the native code. The only obvious thing wrong with the code in the Q is the calling convention.

Answer (score 1):

In Your c++ code insert `__stdcall`

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall int iterateAndTest(int testSize, char* testHash);
```

in C#

```
[DllImport("yourdll.dll", EntryPoint="iterateAndTest", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int iterateAndTest(int testSize, string testHash);
```

use `cout` in your C++ function, if the function is called output will be displayed in output window if you are using Visual Studio.
try placing your c++ dll in your output directory

Possible Errors: dll not found or entry point exception will be thrown.